# toDataURL() file size increase

Tags: javascript, canvas, todataurl

When I upload a certain file in my browser, the file is type jpeg and size of file is 2MB, but when I encode my file to base64 using `canvas.toDataURL()`, the size of the resulting file is about 9MB.

Why is the base64-encoded file 3-4 times larger than the original file?

I have seen that I can specify an option for `toDataURl(type, quality)`, but I can't use it for a png file, just for jpeg, and I want a png.

Comment: Because 64 is smaller than 256.

Comment: To reiterate, base64 means that each byte of the original file is stored across three bytes of ASCII text. Thus, it's 3X larger by design. This is useful because every byte of base64 is URL-safe, whereas most bytes in general are not.

Comment: It's not 3x larger, it's 1/3 larger. This is because a typical byte is encoded in 8 bits (`2^8 == 256`) and a Base64-encoded character can only hold 6 bits (`2^6 == 64`). A clear example is: `btoa('hi there my friend... ;)').length` (**32**) vs. `'hi there my friend... ;)'.length` (**24**). The problem here is you started with a jpeg file and went to png. Jpeg has lossy compression and png has lossless (it's 1/4 the size of a raw bmp file).

Answer (score 0):

Bade-64 will only (and always) make a binary representation 33% larger. This is because three octets are spread over four bytes so that the value of those can be represented as printable ASCII chars, and therefor being transport safe.

The final size is determined by the binary array that needs to be encoded. In addition there will be an uri-header of a few bytes prepending the encoded data.

PNG files are loss-less and tend to be larger than JPEG (not in all cases though). It's expected that we will have to deal with larger files independent on the Base-64 encoding that follows when we use PNG files. PNG has variable compression too as it uses gzip to compress the image data, but unfortunately, we don't have access to this through the context method.

Comment: Thank's all for all reply, I didn't know all information you post